# how to dynamically add / remove constraints in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

We are using optaplanner for VRP. One challenge we have is many of our constraints are specific to a local area. For example, in one state Technician can't cross state line where as in other states technicians can cross state line.

Under such scenario we want create a generic solution where user can add hard constraints and generic solution pick that constraint from data base to provide solution.

Has anyone designed such a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use different `<scoreDrl>` elements:

- general.drl
- ny-specific.drl
- ca-specific.drl
- tx-specific.drl
- ...

Or if you need to solve a single dataset that contains both tx and ny employees, then do something like

```
class Employee {
    State state;
}

rule noCross
when
    Employee(state = "Texas") // doesn't apply to California
    // ... crosses lines
then
    ...
end
```